# Apache2 LDAPS configuration fails to bind/accept credentials

Tags: ldap, apache2.4

This is my first time posting so sorry in advance if I do things incorrectly. I will substitute ip's and usernames.

I have a windows Active Directory setup and I am trying to use this for authentication to a webpage I have on a separate Ubuntu 18.04 server. I am attempting to use apache2 (2.4.18) in order to set this up. Documentation online seems fairly straight forward but I have not been successful. First, I cannot use the <Location "/auth">  tags as it seems to simply not work at all. I have to use the <Directory /auth>  tag.

The AD server uses a self signed certificate and I have had trouble getting it to trust it with LDAPTrustedGlobalCert. I was getting `[Can't contact LDAP server]` but LDAPVerifyServerCert Off seems to let me get past that hurdle for now.

The biggest issue that I have is I do not think the bind is working. When just loading the webpage I see this show up in the error log:

```
[authz_core:debug] [pid 2397] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client <myclientIP>:56969] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[authz_core:debug] [pid 2397] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client <myclientIP>:56969] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
```

From there I enter credentials to try and authenticate and I get:

```
[Thu Aug 27 08:36:22.831527 2020] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 2396] mod_authnz_ldap.c(520): [client <myClientIP>:56887] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldaps://<myLDAPIP>/dc=my,dc=example,dc=com?uid
[Thu Aug 27 08:36:22.888784 2020] [authnz_ldap:info] [pid 2396] [client <myClientIP>:56887] AH01695: auth_ldap authenticate: user <myUser> authentication failed; URI /auth/ [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind() failed][Invalid credentials]
[Thu Aug 27 08:36:22.888825 2020] [auth_basic:error] [pid 2396] [client <myClientIP>:56887] AH01617: user <myUser>: authentication failure for "/auth/": Password Mismatch
```

This is my configuration for apache. I left commented lines in so you can see a couple of the many variations that I have tried:

```
LDAPVerifyServerCert Off

<Directory "/var/www/html/auth">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication required"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL ldaps://<myLDAPIP>/dc=my,dc=example,dc=com?uid
#AuthLDAPURL ldaps://<myLDAPIP>:636/cn=Users,dc=my,dc=example,dc=com
AuthLDAPBindDN <myUser>
#AuthLDAPBindDN cn=<myUser>,dc=my,dc=example,dc=com
AuthLDAPBindPassword <myPassword>
Require valid-user
#require ldap-group cn=Users,dc=my,dc=example,dc=com
#require ldap-group cn=Users
LogLevel debug
</Directory>
```

I have searched all over and tried many configurations but I do not see why it does not work with this one. I have at least three other programs that use LDAPS with this Active Directory server. The difference is they all had built in support for it and I did not have to do anything with apache.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually continued trying multiple configurations and finally found one that worked. Below Is the functioning code:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/auth">
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Authentication required"
 AuthBasicProvider ldap
 AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://<myLDAPIP>/dc=my,dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName"
 AuthLDAPBindDN "myUser@my.example.com"
 AuthLDAPBindPassword "<Password>"
 Require valid-user
LogLevel debug
</Directory>
```

*If your certificate is not trusted you can add LDAPVerifyServerCert Off which should be outside of the virtualhost block